# How can a reference variable be returned into a function?

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, reference

```
#inlcude<iostream>
using namespace std;

int & change(int);
int a[5]={10,20,30,40,50};
int main()
{
       int i;
       for(i=0;i<5;i++)
           change(i)=a[i]+5;

       for(i=0;i<5;i++)
           cout<<"   "<<a[i]<<endl;
}

int & change(int i)
{
        return a[i];
}
```

It works. How can we right function left side? Why it did not give me error lvalue is required?

Please explain how it works and how reference variable return in function?

Comment: What do you think is the problem? `change(i)` yields a reference to an int, and you can assign to a reference just fine.

Comment: does it work like a pointer ?

Comment: References should be covered in your introductory book.

Comment: The return type is an lvalue in fact. non-const references can only bind to lvalues, and you are binding to an array access, which is an lvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an lvalue.

Non-const references can only bind to lvalues. You are returning a reference to an array in memory. That is an lvalue. So it works.

This would not work:

```
int & change(i) {
    return 7;
}
```

7 has no memory address, it is a constant. It will not bind to the return type.

Answer (score 4):

Here, `change(i)` is returning values of type `int` by reference.

**Returning values by reference in C++**

A C++ program can be made easier to read and maintain by using references rather than pointers (no segmentation faults). A C++ function can return a reference in a similar way as it returns a pointer.

When a function returns a reference, it returns an implicit pointer to its return value. This way, a function can be used on the left side of an assignment statement. And so `change(i)=a[i]+5;` is an acceptable and correct statement.

A key difference between a pointer and a reference however, is that the reference can't be `NULL`, while the pointer can. The reference must be initialized when it is declared.

```
int i;
int &j = i;      // Acceptable
int &k;          // Not Acceptable
int &l = NULL;   // Not Acceptable
int *p = NULL;   // Acceptable
int *p1 = &i;    // Acceptable
```

Answer (score 0):

You array consist of referenced on the value. Your `change(i)` return reference to value, and after you modificate it

Comment: The array doesn't contain references to values. You can retrieve references to the values.